# Simulated tiled input field

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to simulate a fluid tiled input (a responsive text input field with a square tile for every character). So far I got a pretty decent result, but there are a couple of issues I cannot fully figure out and I thought maybe someone here might come out with a solution (or a better one).

Here's my code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro');

* { box-sizing: border-box; } 
.tiled-input { position: relative; }

.tiles {
    display: flex;
    background: black;
    padding: 0 0.2vw;
}

.tile {
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    margin: 0.4vw 0.2vw;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.tile:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

input {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    font-family: "Source Code Pro";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-indent: 2vw;
    font-size: 7.5vw;
    letter-spacing: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tiled-input">
        <div class="tiles">
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" maxlength="12">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Issues:**

1. I'd like to improve (maybe some `calc()` expression?) the `letter-spacing` value to be sure that characters are always centered for all widths. Right now I got it for large devices but there are some sizes in which the letters are slightly misplaced...
2. I need it to have 12 tiles, but when I input the last character the cursor moves to wait the 13rd and it shifts the whole input, displacing the characters. The only solution I could think of for this is adding `overflow: hidden` to `.tiled-input` and make the `input` like `width: 120%` but I'd like a better approach.

Comment: I'm kinda busy right now but I have tried something that you can use that could be better. You'll need to mess around with it but I think you can get the desired behavior using `repeating-linear-gradient`. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9huogsvc/).

Comment: Does it have to be HTML/CSS only or is Javascript acceptable?

Comment: Thanks @Phiter, I'll explore the approach with `repeating-linear-gradient` but from the top of my head I'm guessing I'll face the same issue with `letter-spacing` since the problem is not drawing the tiles but placing the characters.

Comment: Chris Coyier has a CodePen sample of a solution for this type of approach relying on an SVG background to create the line separations: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/kKdCz

Comment: @APAD1 JS could be acceptable, HTML/CSS only is preferred

Comment: Thanks @RobertC I'll take a look

Comment: You're right @TemaniAfif, I didn't find any references...

Comment: you want to close as duplicate ? :) the other answer is suitable for you ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think so. I'll give it a try.